# How to Write One method for Both After Insert And After Update Trigger

Tags: trigger

i have User object when after insert and after Update  populate some values. my question can i write one method for both events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly do so. The usual point of splitting out logic in to different methods is legibility. Many "trigger frameworks" actually do have a single method, that then branches depending on the trigger context. Here's one such example:

```
trigger X on Y (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after delete, after undelete) {
  XTriggerHandler.execute(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
}
```

...

```
public class XTriggerHandler {
  public static void execute(X[] oldRecords, X[] newRecords) {
    switch on (Trigger.operationType) {
      when AFTER_INSERT {
        doAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
      }
      when AFTER_UPDATE {
        doAfterUpdate(oldRecords, newRecords);
      }
    }
  }
  public static void doAfterInsert(X[] newRecords) {
    // Logic here
  }
  public static void doAfterUpdate(X[] oldRecords, X[] newRecords) {
    // Logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call one method from both of the events like after-insert/after-update.

**Example 1:**

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (after insert, after update) {
    TriggerHandlerName.method();
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (after insert, after update, before delete) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        TriggerHandlerName.method();
    }

    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.delete){
        // some other fuction before delete.
    }
}
```

> Please mind that some of the trigger variables are not on available in some or either cases. Like you don't have oldMap, old available in insert trigger.

Comment: Can u help me on below Code

Comment: @TejaMani I would request you to please ask another question because what you are asking now is different from original question, also the place where you have put your code is for answering the question, not for asking.

Comment: ya ok.sry for that